# Learning from Michael Trott's Guidebook with V8 or later

Tags: compatibility

I am not sure this question is suitable for this site. Please let me know if my question is too vague or if it is hard to give a clear anwser.

I'm a new user of *Mathematica*. My *Mathematica* use began with version 8. I think I'm reasonably familiar with the core language of *Mathematica*, but I want to get better acquainted with it's applications to various fields such as visualization.

I find Michael Trott's four big volumes, *The Mathematica Guidebook*, a very good resource, but find it a problem that the books are written for V4 and V5.

As I stated above, I am a user of a later version of *Mathematica*, so I have little knowledge of versions before V6. The core language of *Mathematica* hasn't changed a lot since V5, but other parts did (the graphics capabilities for example).

So, my question are:

- Are there any tips/suggestions/references for making the best use of this rather old book?
- How do I deal with the code compatibility issues?

Comment: related, but not a duplicate, might be interesting for you: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/what-mathematica-book-to-buy

Comment: @PinguinDirk Thank you. Leonid's book is one of my favorate! The books listed in that question focus on the core language of *Mathematica* so the version issues is not so important.

Comment: @YvesKlett I can't do anything with my poor English :p

Comment: Even if references and API in previous versions may be obsolete but documentation still maintains info on these and suggests new APIs.

Comment: I would think that being a little out of date is an advantage for these books, to be used for learning, rather than a disadvantage (it certainly is a disadvantage if they are used as a reference). This gives you a chance to figure out the differences and make the learning process more active :)

Answer (score 7):

*(too long for a comment)*

I think there isn't many problems about the code compatibility. You can learn a lot from the book without focusing on any code details.

It's a pity that the book doesn't get up-to-date with the newest MMA version. (I guess it's mainly because MMA has been updated much more frequently after version 5.) But I think it's still worth reading.

What I like the *Guidebook* most is that it has lots and lots of very interesting examples on varied topics, everyone can easily dive in from their interested aspects, math/physics/etc., and drift into *Mathematica* at last. You will see how to realize some well-known algorithms, or see how to model some physical systems, or how to draw some beautiful visualizations, with *MMA style*. You can read it like a *"collected stories"* written in MMA, follow the references you're interested in. Also, you can of course think about how *you* would solve the very problems with the *current* version of MMA. I bet it would be fun. :)

Answer (score 7):

Some of the more graphics-related issues (eg `GraphicsArray`) seem to be fixed automatically by *Mathematica* version 9:

[image: graphics array]

Others are more problematic, unfortunately - but perhaps you could post a question. There are people here who have been using *Mathematica* for longer than some other people have lived...:)

The interactive features of the notebooks don't appear to work every time, but you might consider copying some of the code into a new notebook, to get the default stylesheet (and useful syntax colouring). Each section is self-contained, which is useful.

I think enough of the code works for the books to be very useful resources:

```
Module[{newVs, startVs, used, s = Sqrt[3], c = 0, iter = 7},
 (* attach new Vs to given one *)
 newVs[v : Polygon[{p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_, p5_, p6_}]] :=
  Block[{\[ScriptD]2 = (p2 - p1)/4, \[ScriptD]4 = (p4 - p1)/2, p7, 
    p8, p9, p10,   p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19},
          p7 = p2 + \[ScriptD]4; p8 = p3 + 2 \[ScriptD]4; 
   p9 = p4 + \[ScriptD]4; p10 = p5 + 2 \[ScriptD]4; 
          p11 = p6 + \[ScriptD]4; p12 = p3 + \[ScriptD]2; 
   p13 = p12 + \[ScriptD]4; p14 = p8 - \[ScriptD]2; 
          p15 = p9 + \[ScriptD]2; p16 = p5 + \[ScriptD]2; 
   p17 = p16 + \[ScriptD]4; p18 = p10 - \[ScriptD]2; 
          p19 = p18 - \[ScriptD]4;
     If[(* only two Vs can have a common edge *) 
           used[#1/2] >= 2, 
      Sequence @@ {}, (used[#] = used[#] + 1) & /@
            (*   mark midpoints of new edges *)
            (Plus @@@ 
          Partition[Append[#2, #2[[1]]], 2, 1]/2); 
      Polygon[#2]] & @@@
        (* the four new Vs *) 
      Transpose[{{p2 + p3, p3 + p4, p4 + p5, p5 + p6},
                {{p3, p2, p7, p12, p13, p8}, {p3, p8, p14, p15, p9, p4},
                  {p5, p4, p9, p16, p17, p10}, {p5, p10, p18, p19, 
        p11, p6}}}]];
 (* three initial Vs *) 
 startVs = Polygon /@ (* use rational vertices *) Rationalize[N[
     {{{0, 0}, {2 s, 2}, {2 s, 0}, {s, -1}, {s, -3}, {0, -4}}, 
        {{0, 0}, {0, -4}, {-s, -3}, {-s, -1}, {-2 s, 0}, {-2 s, 2}}, 
        {{0, 0}, {-2 s, 2}, {-s, 3}, {0, 2}, {s, 3}, {2 s, 2}}}/4, 
     30], 0];   
 (* no edge is used yet *) used[_] := 0;
 Show[Graphics[(* 
    pseudorandom coloring *) {Hue[Cos[Sec[c++]]], #} &  /@ 
      (* iterate attaching new Vs *)
     Flatten[NestList[Flatten[newVs /@ #] &, startVs, iter]]] /.
   Polygon[l_] :> {Polygon[l], {GrayLevel[0], 
      Line[Append[l, l[[1]]]]}},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image: cube]