# Purpose of construct `With[{var=myComputation[...]}, var/;True]`?

Tags: idiomatic-usage

Could someone please give an illustrative example showing the purpose of construct of form `With[{var=myComputation[...]}, var/;True]`?  Also, I wonder what kind of reference material are available for getting familiar with programming idioms for Mathematica.  I mean besides the basic syntax that one can learn and re-learn from standard documentation, there are repeated patterns that programmers use.  Somewhat similar to design patterns and "proramming pearls" for Java.

Comment: It is known as the "Trott-Strzebonski method for In-Place Evaluation."  If you search for the word "Strzebonski" you will find numerous references.  I am closing this question as this is well explained already.  (See the link in the header.)

Comment: Ok, so the other half of the question is also refused?

Comment: Sorry, I should not have ignored that.  Those questions are already addressed in various posts, including: [(18)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18),
[(5059)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5059),
[(16485)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16485),
[(24988)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24988)