# Good books about Mathematica?

Tags: reference-request

I really like the book by Leonid Shifrin (http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/). It does a great job explaining the general principles behind Mathematica's syntax. However it hasn't been updated since 2008. Although I suspect that many of the principles outlined in this book are still valid, it would be nice to have a more up to date reference.

The documentation is also great, but sometimes I feel it is lacking in depth. I also found [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5059/534), which also looks outdated. I am asking this in the hope of finding new, modern, sources.

Can you recommend a book with a similar depth to Leonid's, that is more up to date (if there is any)? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this enough? :) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/5478

Comment: I have the four books from Michael Trott. Superb texts. Though a bit old, they are quite comprehensive about the fundamentals of MMA capabilities.

Comment: @Kuba I saw that list, but the books listed there are all pre-2010. Otherwise it's an excellent collection of resources, but I am looking for books, specifically.

Comment: With this day and age, physical books about programming language are out of date before they are published. Also, everything is on-line, much faster to search and find something than using physical book. But one book I really liked is Heikki Ruskeepaa Mathematica navigator. But again, this book was not updated since 2009.  There is also Sal Mangano Mathematica cookbook which is nice.

Comment: I still hope to get some time on my hands to update the book, and if I have yet some more, perhaps write another one which would have a deeper coverage and more advanced topics as well. Can't tell when this happens, though, my plate is full for quite a while.

Comment: @Nasser I never said it had to be a physical book. It can be online, or a PDF (like Leonid's book).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I am sure a lot of people would be happy if an updated version of your book came out.

Comment: @becko, I put a bounty on the Q&A you indicate wanted updating (it's actually one of the explicit reasons one can check off on the bounty form).  Maybe you can get an answer that way, and the answers will stay together.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Trott books are amazing. But if you can understand the code there, then you must be really good!  I struggle each time I try to read some of the code there (the more complicated ones). Too advanced for normal users to follow I think. The books contain great graphics. But I think the code could have written in a more easier way to understand for us normal users.