# For a multivariable polynomial of degree t, how can you find the coefficients of monomials of degree t?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Hello Mathematica StackExchange community,

I'm hoping that someone can be of help!

Let p be a fixed prime. I have a multivariable polynomial g (of degree t). I need a list of all the monomial terms of g which satisfy:

1. Degree of the monomial term is t.
2. Each of the exponents in the monomial term is less than or equal to p-2

I have been playing around with the Mathematica commands (`MonomialList`, `Coefficient`, `CoefficientRules`, `Expand`, etc.), but have not been successful in reaching my goal.

If anybody can provide some help, it is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Sincerely,
Richard M. Low

UPDATE:---------------------------------

Due to kglr's help, I have been able to make some progress on my problem. Here is kglr's original Mathematica code:

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, f]
t = 4;
p = 5;
poly = (x + 2 y + z)^t + x^2;

f = Select[And[Total@# == t, Max[#] <= p - 2] &@Exponent[#, {x, y, z}] &];

selected = f@MonomialList[poly]
```

I'm hoping that kglr (or somebody else) can help me modify it slightly.

Since the typical polynomials that I will be working with may have (literally) billions (~ 6^14) of monomial terms, I would like for the output of f to be 1 monomial term (not the entire list) which satisfies the two conditions (in my original post) AND whose coefficient is not equal to 0 (mod p).

This will greatly decrease the runtime and memory usage of the Mathematica program. The runtime of the original Mathematica program went past several days and I ended up aborting the calculation.

Again, I appreciate any help that the Mathematica StackExchange can provide. I am completely incompetent in Mathematica programming.

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely,
Richard M. Low

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, f]
t = 4;
p = 5;
poly = (x + 2 y + z)^t + x^2;

f = Select[And[Total@# == t, Max[#] <= p - 2] &@Exponent[#, {x, y, z}] &];

selected = f @ MonomialList[poly]
```

> {8 x^3 y, 4 x^3 z, 24 x^2 y^2, 24 x^2 y z, 6 x^2 z^2, 32 x y^3, 
>        48 x y^2 z, 24 x y z^2, 4 x z^3, 32 y^3 z, 24 y^2 z^2, 8 y z^3}

```
Complement[MonomialList @ poly, selected]
```

> {x^2, x^4, 16 y^4, z^4}

**Update:** *"I would like for the output of f to be 1 monomial term (not the entire list) which satisfies the two conditions."*

Just replace `Select` with `SelectFirst`:

```
f2 = SelectFirst[And[And[Total@# == t, Max[#] <= p - 2] &@Exponent[#, {x, y, z}], 
  Mod[# /. x | y | z -> 1, p] != 0] &]

selected2 = f2@MonomialList[poly]
```

> 8 x^3 y

**Update 2:** A faster approach: use `Expand` instead of `MonomialList`:

```
f2 @ Expand[poly]
```

> 8 x^3 y

Comment: kglr, I think that your Mathematica code works! Let me try some initial tests to see what happens. I'll get back to you very soon! Thanks again and I'll report back my findings.

Comment: Your Mathematica code works! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I am hoping that kglr's Mathematica code can be slightly modified. Please see the UPDATE in my original post.

Comment: kglr, Thank you for the suggestion of replacing with "SelectFirst". What about checking that the monomial term has coefficient not equal to 0 (mod p), before outputting the desired monomial term? Where should I put the "Mod p" check condition?

Comment: @richmlow, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your modified Mathematica code has cut the typical runtime in half. I am currently writing a mathematics research article and will submit it for publication in the not-too-distant future. You have been of great help and I would like to acknowledge your contribution (within the paper). If you are are comfortable with this, please send me an email (richard.low@sjsu.edu). If you would prefer to remain anonymous, that is also fine! Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, do you have any recommendations for a good book on Mathematica programming? I would prefer a book which would give me a foundation which is similar to your particular powerful style of Mathematica programming.

Comment: @richmlow, my pleasure. Thank you for the kind offer to cite my post in your article. You can cite stack exchange content using a link to the relevant pages. Re good books on Mathematica programming [this q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5059/125) contains several links.

Comment: Thank you for the link!

Comment: kglr, Also, thank you for your Update 2 (suggestion of using Expand, instead of MonomialList). On my "test" polynomial, the runtime was reduced from approx. 1.5 minutes to around 50 seconds. Every bit helps, since the polynomials have 4^14 or more monomial terms. If you come up with any other optimizations, please let me know! Thanks again!

Comment: kglr, It's strange....sometimes "Expand" is considerably faster than "MonomialList" and other times, "MonomialList" is faster than "Expand". It depends on the polynomial.

Comment: kglr, Do you think that it is possible to use the Mathematica functions "Catch" and "Throw" (and slightly modify your nice Mathematica code) so that a single "desired" monomial (or empty set) is outputted immediately (without calculating the entire monomial list), and the program then terminates?? Assuming that this can be done, I think that this would GREATLY decrease the runtime. Right now, the runtimes are quite long, due to the size of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use the output of `CoefficientRules[]` to get what is wanted. To wit,

```
With[{t = 4, p = 5},
     KeyValueMap[#2 Inner[Power, {x, y, z}, #1, Times] &, 
                 KeySelect[CoefficientRules[(x + 2 y + z)^t + x^2, {x, y, z}], 
                           Tr[#] == t && Max[#] <= p - 2 &]]]
   {8 x^3 y, 4 x^3 z, 24 x^2 y^2, 24 x^2 y z, 6 x^2 z^2, 32 x y^3, 48 x y^2 z,
    24 x y z^2, 4 x z^3, 32 y^3 z, 24 y^2 z^2, 8 y z^3}
```

To add in the further $\bmod p$ restriction, you can use another call to `Select[]`:

```
With[{t = 4, p = 5},
     KeyValueMap[#2 Inner[Power, {x, y, z}, #1, Times] &, 
                 Drop[Select[KeySelect[CoefficientRules[(x + 2 y + z)^t + x^2,
                                                        {x, y, z}], 
                                       Tr[#] == t && Max[#] <= p - 2 &],
                             ! Divisible[#, p] &], {2, -1}]]]
   {8 x^3 y}
```

where I use the explicit test `Divisible[]` for filtering.

Comment: Hello J.M., Thank you for giving an alternative Mathematica program in answering my original question! Right now, SJSU is in the middle of Final Exam week. So, I haven't had a chance to look at your program. However, this is at the top of my "To Do" list! Thank you again and I'll be in touch with you (via this StackExchange thread) soon.

Comment: Hello J.M., Your alternate Mathematica program also helped in answering my original question. Thank you for your help and generosity!