# Recommend Mathematica Book

Tags: education

I've been using Mathematica for a few years now, but at a fairly formal level, more for creating graphs in calculus as a student. However, as a graduate student, I would like to focus on ordinary differential equations.

What is the best Mathematica book for a non-programmer who wants to start studying ordinary differential equations? I would like to improve my skills.

Comment: I do not know ifit the best, but there is: "Differential equations with mathematica" from M.L.Abell and J.P.Braselton

Comment: The document  `tutorial/DSolveOverview`  `tutorial/NumericalOperationsOnFunctions#17230` and `tutorial/NumericalOperationsOnFunctions#8415` are some  good sources to read.

Comment: My recommendation would be to learn the math from math books, not from Mathematica books. Unless you don't really care about the math -- for instance, not a grad student in mathematics but in, say, chemistry or engineering or some other field that uses diff. eq. The context of the question and goals (what skills are to be improved) are not yet clear to me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I fully understand how you mean it. Perhaps I was not clear enough in my wording. I am a graduate student in mathematics with an interest in ordinary differential equations. What I want to improve in Mathematica is the following, how to correctly transfer the problems I have on paper to Mathematica.

Comment: **how to correctly transfer the problems I have on paper to Mathematica** are you interested in numerical solutions or analytical? But either way, the best way is to just study examples. You do not need a book.  Mathematica gives you a blackbox function. You give it an input, it gives back an output.  To learn how to talk to this blackbox, is to look at examples and read the documentation for the API.

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/what-mathematica-book-to-buy